# Manage external authenticated API

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm looking to use Azure API Management to provide a centralized API for some external, authenticated APIs (Twitter, etc.), utilizing [application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only). I want to provide specific tweets, etc. to a dashboard-like mobile app without users needing to authenticate with their own account for each service.

I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples on doing this so far. [Policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn894080.aspx) look promising, but I haven't been able to prove them out yet. Or possibly creating my own API App for each external service (to handle the authentication properly) and then managing that API via API Management.

Anyone have thoughts/ideas on better ways of accomplishing this? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to make a request to an API defined in API Management that takes your request, validates it and then forwards it on to twitter (for example) along with the twitter client credentials.  If I have got the gist of this, then yes policies can do this for you easily.

Comment: @DarrelMiller yeah, that's it. And I was finally able to get it working, too. Using [these instructions](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) I obtained the needed OAuth info, then just set an inbound policy of set-header with the OAuth info, and it worked right away. Thanks for keeping me on the right path!

Comment: That's awesome to hear.

Answer (score 2):

*Thanks to @DarrelMiller for keeping me on the correct path*

The solution ended up being just needing to pass the correct bearer token as a header, accomplished with Set-Header in the inbound policy of the operation. [Twitter has non-trivial instructions](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) on how to obtain the bearer token for their service.

Example:

```
<inbound>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
    </set-header>
    <base />
</inbound>
```